# Django migration: all the columns are not generated as the model

Tags: python, mysql, django

For all the tables some of columns are generated and some of columns didn't.

Here is my models

personalInfo.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Students(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_dept = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_sec = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class StudentDetails(models.Model):
    students = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    present_address = models.TextField
    permanent_address = models.TextField
    student_phone = models.BigIntegerField
    gpo_box_number = models.IntegerField

class Teachers(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    teacher_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teacher_dept = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class TeacherDetails(models.Model):
    teachers = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    present_address = models.TextField
    permanent_address = models.TextField
    teacher_phone = models.BigIntegerField
    gpo_box_number = models.IntegerField
```

studentAdvising.py

```
from django.db import models
from personalInfo.models import Students, Teachers

# Create your models here.

class Advising(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_matter = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    comment = models.TextField
    starting_time = models.TimeField
    ending_time = models.TimeField
    date = models.DateField
```

migration details for personalInfo.py

```
# Generated by Django 2.0 on 2018-01-03 17:43

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='StudentDetails',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Students',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('student_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('student_id', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('student_dept', models.CharField(max_length=30)),
                ('student_sec', models.CharField(max_length=2)),
            ],
        ),
         migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TeacherDetails',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Teachers',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('teacher_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('teacher_id', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('teacher_dept', models.CharField(max_length=30)),
             ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='teacherdetails',
            name='teachers',

field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='personalInfo.Teachers'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='studentdetails',
            name='students',

field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='personalInfo.Students'),
        ),
    ]
```

migration details for studentAdvising

```
# Generated by Django 2.0 on 2018-01-03 17:43

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('personalInfo', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Advising',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('subject_matter', models.CharField(max_length=400)),
                ('student', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='personalInfo.Students')),
                ('teacher', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='personalInfo.Teachers')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

tables in database,

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------------+
| Tables_in_studentAdvising   |
+-----------------------------+
| auth_group                  |
| auth_group_permissions      |
| auth_permission             |
| auth_user                   |
| auth_user_groups            |
| auth_user_user_permissions  |
| django_admin_log            |
| django_content_type         |
| django_migrations           |
| django_session              |
| personalInfo_studentdetails |
| personalInfo_students       |
| personalInfo_teacherdetails |
| personalInfo_teachers       |
| studentAdvisingApp_advising |
+-----------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM personalInfo_students;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_name | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| student_id   | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| student_dept | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| student_sec  | varchar(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM personalInfo_studentdetails;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| students_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM personalInfo_teachers;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| teacher_name | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| teacher_id   | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| teacher_dept | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM personalInfo_teacherdetails;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| teachers_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM studentAdvisingApp_advising;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject_matter | varchar(400) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| student_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| teacher_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can't understand where the problem is. And there is no good informaton about it on google. What should I do??

Comment: What columns are not constructed?

Comment: You are missing parentheses in your model fields

Comment: @TONMOY: yes, you did not construct a `Field` *instance*, only a *reference* to a `Field` subclass.

Comment: Thanks brothers, I used pycharm, it gives the field but don't give the parenthesis with it that is why I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class definitions you write things like:

```
class TeacherDetails(models.Model):
    teachers = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    present_address = models.TextField  # call missing
    permanent_address = models.TextField  # call missing
    teacher_phone = models.BigIntegerField  # call missing
    gpo_box_number = models.IntegerField  # call missing
```

So the **call** to the constructor is missing. You did not associate `present_address` with a `TextField` *instance*, you associated it with the `TextField` type instead.

You need to cll the constructor, so:

```
class TeacherDetails(models.Model):
    teachers = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    present_address = models.TextField()  # call to constructor
    permanent_address = models.TextField()  # call to constructor
    teacher_phone = models.BigIntegerField()  # call to constructor
    gpo_box_number = models.IntegerField()  # call to constructor
```

Django will look for attributes associated with `Model` subclasses that are *instances* of a `Field` (not references to a (sub)class of `Field`). These are then mapped to columns in databases.

Comment: Bro after adding the parenthesis when I did makemigrations then it gave me 2 options to choose,

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'gpo_box_number' to studentdetails without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:

Which option should I choose??

Comment: In case there is no data yet, I think you beter remove the initial migrations, and reset the database. Otherwise you have to think what values to fill in currently for `present_address`, etc. for the teacher you already filled in (this is usually option (1)).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `type(models.TextField)` >>> `type`. What is a `type`?

Comment: For removing the initial migrations, should I delete the initial.py file from the migration directory and do the makemigration again??
If I choose not to delete my initial migrations then which field should be filled with null values of data?? Should I do it for all the fields in models or only to the field I want to add?? They are saying they will set all existing rows with a null value does that means all the informations on other fields will be gone??

Comment: @TONMOY: the problem is that an `IntegerField` can not be `null` (by default). So you can add `null=True`, or you have to define a default value.

Comment: @TONMOY: in case you want to "restart" the migrations (losing the data), you better drop and recreate the database, and remove the migration files. Then you run `makemigrations` an `migrate`. As said in the comment, you will lose all data. But if you are still in development phase, usually there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

**Add fields like this:**

```
comment = models.TextField()
starting_time = models.TimeField()
ending_time = models.TimeField()
date = models.DateField()
```

**you need to add parentheses in the end.**